# Run-Time Error '91' - Object Variable or With Block Variable not set when referencing a Check Box

Tags: vba, forms, outlook, outlook-2013

I have read through all the help listed and can't resolve my issue.

I am creating a form in Outlook 2013, and would like to have some of the fields visible when certain conditions are met - I have been attempting to write some VBA code for this.. but am getting the error.

This is my Code;

```
Sub AltSMSNumber()

Dim CheckBox2 As CheckBox
Dim TextBox2 As TextBox
Dim Label2 As Label

Set CheckBox2 = CheckBox2
Set TextBox2 = TextBox2
Set Label2 = Label2

If CheckBox2.Value = False Then

    Set TextBox2.Visible = True
    Set Label2.Visible = True

Else

    Set TextBox2.Visible = False
    Set Label2.Visible = False


End If

End Sub
```

I have set the Checkbox on the form to be true by default, and only want TextBox2 and Label2 to be visible when the Checkbox is unchecked (false).

I have looked over all of the names - and they are all definitely named as I have noted in the code.

It breaks at; *If CheckBox2.Value = False Then*
Telling me the Object isn't set.

Can anyone point out my error??

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

The problem is here:

```
Set CheckBox2 = CheckBox2
```

You can't declare a variable and then set it to itself.  Did you intend to assign another, existing check box to it?

Note, you have the same issue with the other variables you're using.  Maybe you should look over a VBA tutorial.  There are plenty online.

Comment: I presumed that the asker was trying to set a reference to the form's CheckBox2 element (in which case it'd be better to use `Set cb2 = formName.CheckBox2` and change the name used to reference it.  Also shouldn't use `Set` on the textbox and label  `Visible` properties being changed...

Answer (score 0):

If you have not renamed your Textbox or Label then this should work ..

```
Sub AltSMSNumber()
 If CheckBox2.Value = False Then
     Set TextBox2.Visible = True
     Set Label2.Visible = True
 Else
    Set TextBox2.Visible = False
    Set Label2.Visible = False
End If
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

inside userform code pane with the `Me` keyword you reference the userform

use it and get to its members (like its controls are) by simply typing a dot (`.`) and then the member name

```
Sub AltSMSNumber()
    With Me '<-- reference the userform
        .TextBox2.Visible = Not .CheckBox2
        .Label2.Visible = Not .CheckBox2
    End With
End Sub
```

but if you want that behavior as "automatic" then use the `CheckBox2` `Click` event handler

```
Private Sub CheckBox2_Click()
    With Me '<-- reference the userform
        .TextBox2.Visible = Not .CheckBox2
        .Label2.Visible = Not .CheckBox2
    End With
End Sub
```

Comment: @Lilliputian_83, did you get through it?